# Subscription and Recurring Payment system via stripe

Tags: php, zend-framework2, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, recurring-billing

I want to integrate stripe payment gateway for user subscription and recurring payments. But I am not understanding How I manage same in stripe.

Because I am only getiing stripetoken and my custom post data via POST request. $_POST.

I have created stripe form like this

```
<form action="/paypal/ipnstripe" method="post" id="stripe_payment">
<input type="hidden" id="custom" name="custom" value="">
<script id="stripe_payment_script" 
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
data-description="Access for a year"
data-amount="5000"
data-locale="auto"
data-email="example@mail.com"></script>
</form>
```

And ipnstripe action code is

```
require_once ('vendor/stripe/init.php');

    //echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);die;

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_qImt2sC7AFfv9lXqwYgPlUKm");

    $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $c_data  = explode("||",$_POST['custom']);
    $email = $c_data[0];
    $amount = $c_data[1];
    $pwd = $c_data[2];
    $plan_subs = $c_data[3];
    $trial = $c_data[4];
    $plan = $c_data[5];
    $plan_id = $c_data[6];
    $coupon = $c_data[7];

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'source'  => $token
    ));

    $subs = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
      "customer" => $customer->id,
      "items" => array(
        array(
          "plan" => 1,
        ),
      )
    ));
```

Now I wants to add user into my website database if payment completed 
successfully and also manage recurring payments. I am not understanding that how I manage this. In paypal we manage recurring  payment Like this

```
if($myPost['txn_type'] == 'recurring_payment' || $myPost['txn_type'] == 
'subscr_payment')

if($myPost['txn_type'] == 
'recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment')
```

How I manage this in stripe.

Thanx

Comment: You can listen for `customer.subscription.created` webhook events and update your database asynchronously.  Or you could simply create a call after the subscription is made.  If the subscription doesn't have a trial period, then attaching it successfully indicates a successful payment.

Comment: Thanx korben, I want to integrate stripe payment gatway in 3 places of same site. So I have to set webhooks, Am I right ? And If set 3 webhooks then I want to know will they conflict or not ?